# ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated_endpoints'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

Source code:

```
from tensorflow.python.util.deprecation import deprecated_endpoints
```

Error:

```
Import error: cannot import name 'deprecated_endpoints'
```

Could someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: What is your tensorflow version and how did you install it?

Comment: @GinoMempin , I have installed it using "pip" . Version - 1.14.0

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 with tensorflow==1.14.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @GinoMempin I am facing this issue on Windows.